# Meteor: Hide or remove element? What is the best way

Tags: javascript, dom, meteor, handlebars.js

I am quite new with Meteor but have really been enjoying it and this is my first reactive app that I am building.

I would like to know a way that I can remove the `.main` element when the user clicks or maybe a better way would be to remove the existing template (with main content) and then replace with another meteor template?  Something like this would be simple and straightforward in html/js app (user clicks-> remove el from dom) but here it is not all that clear.

I am just looking to learn and for some insight on best practice.

```
//gallery.html
<template name="gallery">
  <div class="main">First run info.... Only on first visit should user see  this info.</div>
  <div id="gallery">
    <img src="{{selectedPhoto.url}}">
  </div>    
</template>  

//gallery.js
firstRun = true;

Template.gallery.events({
  'click .main' : function(){
    $(".main").fadeOut();
    firstRun = false;
  }
})

if (Meteor.isClient) {    

  function showSelectedPhoto(photo){    
    var container = $('#gallery');
    container.fadeOut(1000, function(){          
      Session.set('selectedPhoto', photo);
      Template.gallery.rendered = function(){
        var $gallery = $(this.lastNode);
        if(!firstRun){
          $(".main").css({display:"none"});
          console.log("not");
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
          $gallery.fadeIn(1000);
        }, 1000)
      }        
    });      
  }

  Deps.autorun(function(){
    selectedPhoto = Photos.findOne({active : true});
    showSelectedPhoto(selectedPhoto);        
  });

  Meteor.setInterval(function(){    
       selectedPhoto = Session.get('selectedPhoto');   

       //some selections happen here for getting photos.

    Photos.update({_id: selectedPhoto._id}, { $set: { active: false } });
    Photos.update({_id: newPhoto._id}, { $set: { active: true } });    
  }, 10000 );
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to hide or show an element conditionaly you should use the reactive behavior of Meteor: Add a condition to your template:

```
<template name="gallery">
  {{#if isFirstRun}}
  <div class="main">First run info.... Only on first visit should user see  this info.</div>
  {{/if}}
  <div id="gallery">
    <img src="{{selectedPhoto.url}}">
  </div>    
</template>
```

then add a helper to your template:

```
Template.gallery.isFirstRun = function(){
   // because the Session variable will most probably be undefined the first time
   return !Session.get("hasRun");
}
```

and change the action on click:

```
Template.gallery.events({
  'click .main' : function(){
    $(".main").fadeOut();
    Session.set("hasRun", true);
  }
})
```

you still get to fade out the element but then instead of hiding it or removing it and having it come back on the next `render` you ensure that it will never come back.

the render is triggered by changing the `Session`variable, which is reactive.

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes complete sense and is inline with how I am writing the rest of the app.  Thanks again for the answer and example!

Comment: it is always a pleasure to be of assistance :-)

Comment: Hey Gorb -- I'm learning Meteor for a new project, and this is really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: What if you want to do a show/hide per item in a collection in an #each block. For instance I want to toggle {{someProp}}'s visibility based on a button click. <button class="show-some-prop">Show</button> is in the #each block as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think using conditional templates is a better approach,

```
{{#if firstRun }}
  <div class="main">First run info.... Only on first visit should user see  this info.</div>
{{else}}
  gallery ...
{{/if}}
```

You'll have to make firstRun a session variable, so that it'll trigger DOM updates.

Answer (score 2):

[Meteor is **reactive**](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity). You don't need to write the logic for redrawing the DOM when the data changes. Just write the code that when X button is clicked, Y is removed from the database. That's it; you don't need to trouble yourself with any interface/DOM changes or template removal/redrawing or any of that. Whenever the data that underpins a template changes, Meteor automatically rerenders the template with the updated data. This is Meteor’s core feature.